# View to use external URL

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I want to access ElasticSearch securely via a Django URL. From this request, I will lookup the user's token to get their primary key. Then I will only show ES results that match.

For now, I just want to connect to my ElasticSearch URL. It would kind of work like a "proxy".

Anyway, the following returns the bottom traceback. How do I set it up correctly? Do I need a serialiser

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ElasticViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def my_view(request):
        if True:
           return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:9200/_seach')
```

## urls.py

```
router.register(r'elastic', ElasticViewSet, base_name='Elastic')
```

## Traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  83.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  477.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  437.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  474.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

File "/Users/mac1/Dev/A51/Backend/NewDJ/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get_queryset
  67.             % self.__class__.__name__

Exception Type: AssertionError at /****/elastic/
Exception Value: 'ElasticViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.
```

Comment: The answer is in traceback.

Comment: You are inheriting from ModelViewSet which must have a queryset which points to some Model in your code

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use a model in my code, I just want to redirect via a URL

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you don't want a `ModelViewSet` as there's no `Model`. Just go for the regular `ViewSet`.

Second, please take some time to think about what you want to do and how you want it done. `my_view` is not a `ViewSet` regular action. Returning `HttpResponseRedirect` is not acting as a proxy.

Comment: Ok, I've created another question that more specifically tries to access the API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827690/viewset-to-access-external-api-elastic-search