# Viewset to access external API (elastic search)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to use my ElasticSearch api via Django as a viewset.

This is my attempt, which doesnt work. I don't get errors, but the URL doesn't actually even appear which makes me think my viewset is broken

services.py
    import json
    import requests

```
def get_items(id, title):
    url = 'http://localhost:9200/_search' 
    params = json.loads(request.GET.body)
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:9200/_search', params=params)
    items = r.json()
    return items['results']
```

views.py

```
import services

class ElasticViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self,request):
        item_list = get_items()
        return item_list
        pass
```

urls.py

```
from api.views import ElasticViewSet
router.register(r'elastic', ElasticViewSet, base_name='Elastic')
```

Comment: You should take some time and read the documentation about Django Rest Framework. You shouldn't be using get in the viewset, you shouldn't be using render, you code doesn't define item_list ...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the docs, I've already spent hours reading them without getting this working. Please provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your `get_items` method to return a value.

```
import json
import requests

def get_items(request):
    url = 'http://localhost:9200/_search' 
    params = json.loads(request.body)
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:9200/_search', params=params)
    items = r.json()
    return items['results'] # handle exceptions for fail proof design
```

and call the the method `get_items` in your views,
As for a bare bone, you can do this.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ElasticViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        item_list = get_items(request)
        return Response(data=item_list)
```

Comment: Still no success. Thanks, but it still is NOT showing `elastic` as a URL. DRF does not even list it. I've update my OP to include my URLs.

Comment: is it the real view, the one posted with the question?